# How to remove empty bullet list while doing mail merge in C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, mailmerge

How to remove empty bullet list while doing mail merge in C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

I am doing mail merge using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. Some times merge fields are bullet list and some of the fields have empty value. i want to remove the empty bullet list item if the value is empty.Can you please provide any sample code to achieve this.

Comment: Hello. This question is too broad. Questions are more likely to be answered when the author has already done some research and attempted to solve the problem. Here are the guidelines on how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, here's the `MailMerge` interface for C#. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.mailmerge?view=word-pia

Comment: @dimiguel thanks for the response. My scenario is below.I have below merge fields in a document. These merge fields are bulleted list. I am populating these fields at run time. During run time some of the merge field value is empty. If the value is empty i want to remove that particular bulleted list item.
My Document:
• «M_TEST_1»
• «M_TEST_2»
• «M_TEST_3»
In my scenario «M_TEST_2» field is empty. So i want output like below.
• Value1
• Value3